# Sliding expiration caching in Asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-caching

I have a requirement in my application where I want to clear my cache on specific time and that should happen only once in 24 hours.I tried with the absolute expiration but it is clearing the cache everytime once the time is passed.

I have also tried sliding expiration where I manually calculate time for sliding the duration but somehow it is working for small duration like 3-4 minutes but when I keep it idle for more than 10 minutes cache is not getting cleared out.

Could you please help me in achieving this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `it is clearing the cache everytime once the time is passed.` that's not what you want? If you set time to expire 2pm next day it will clear up that time and repopulate with next expiration at 2pm day after. Can you explain your problem with some example?

Comment: @chetan .. yes I want to clear it only once in a day in the morning 6 AM and after 6 AM fresh call will happen that will repopulate it and after that it should not clear it till next day.

Comment: Then what's the problem using absolute expiration,?

Comment: In absolute it is expiring the cache on each request once the time is passed

Comment: I just wanted to know is there any threshold limit for sliding expiration because when I cached it for 3-4 minutes it is working fine but if I cached it for hours then cache is not getting cleared.

Comment: As its name says it is sliding expiration. So let say you set it to 1 hour. So whenever you access the cached item the expiration is extended to 1 hour from the time it is accessed. If the item is not accessed for 1 hour then only it gets removed from the cache. While in absolute expiration the item is removed from the cache when the duration is over whether access it or not.